# Why is the button click event not fired after textbox leave event?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, button, textbox

I have text box with leave event

```
    private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Leave");
    }
```

and button with click event

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Click");
    }
```

When I enter text in textbox and click the button the leave event fires but click event does not.

How do I fire the click event without invoking `button1_Click` in the leave event?

Comment: The click event does only fire when you click **ON** the textbox itself.

Comment: are you sure you attached the event to the button?

Comment: I get the problem. when you leave the textbox and try to click on the button the leave event fires immediately you try to switch focus so you don't actually get a chance to click the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replace `MessageBox.Show` with `Console.WriteLine` in the `textBox1_Leave` and you will see the button's click event.
In other words, it seems that user interaction in the `Leave` event breaks events chain, because of the focus was captured by `MessageBox`.